# Warnings for uninitialized members disappear on the C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, static-analysis

I compile this simple program:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct Bar
{
    //Bar() = default;
    int d;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;

    printf("%d %d\n", foo.a, foo.b);

    return 0;
}
```

and I get those warnings:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic foo.cpp -o foo
foo.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.cpp:21:9: warning: unused variable ‘bar’ [-Wunused-variable]
     Bar bar;
         ^
foo.cpp:23:11: warning: ‘foo.Foo::b’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     printf("%d %d\n", foo.a, foo.b);
           ^
foo.cpp:23:11: warning: ‘foo.Foo::a’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

Of course, this is what we expect. But when I uncomment the `Bar` default ctor, there is a problem - all warnings disappear.

Why the `Bar` ctor disables warnings for `Foo`?

My GCC version is: `g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 5.4.0 20160609`.

The problem does not occur on the C++03, only on the C++11 or newer.

Comment: g++ (GCC) 6.1.0 displays the warnings [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19043d798802ac4a).

Comment: It's a compiler bug, which as Jarod pointed out, has been fixed.

Comment: @Jarod42 Try it without `-O2`, like OP.

Comment: @T.C. You're right! With `-O1`, `-O2`, `-O3` and `-Os` my code gives warnings in both cases with the GCC 5.4.0.

Comment: In creating the instance of `Bar` class, doing this `Bar bar()`  will show the warnings!

Comment: @Nana - that should not result in a warning about an unused variable `bar`, since `Bar bar()` declares a function, not a variable.

Comment: @Peter I use the same GCC version as it's described in the question and it does result in the same warning as expected. Plus the warning isn't about `bar`, it's about `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a compiler bug, which as Jarod pointed out, has been fixed.